# Repeat macro in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm incredibly new to VBA for Excel, and ashamed to admit that I don't understand what I've read so far!
I'm trying to copy and paste from one sheet to another, and then recopying the results from the second sheet back into the first sheet. I have about 5300 items that I wish to copy - paste from the original sheet. Here's the recorded macro that resulted:

```
Sub Retreive_Code()
    Range("L11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows( _
        "Unique License plate Valuation Algorithm.18March2014.V7.0.Winner!.xlsx"). _
        Activate
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("L2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Complete Unique number sales.2010 - 2012.xlsx").Activate
    Range("M11").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Please let me know if you have any questions at all.
Many thanks

Comment: `Please let me know if you have any questions at all` - we doesn't have any questions. Do _you_ have any questions to us?

Comment: I certainly do! I need to know how I can copy this formula across the complete length of the column using VBA.

Comment: what ranges are you want to copy and where you need to paste them?

Comment: I need to paste the following range (L12:L5283) and would like to paste the results in (K12:K5283)

Comment: Sorry, would like to paste the results in (M12:M5283)

Comment: have you tried to record a macro for copying entire range (L12:L5283), rather than single cell?

Comment: I actually haven't, and I don't think I know how to

Comment: it the same as for single cell:) just select entire range instead single cell and try to record your macro for copying data

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Is this what you are trying?

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub Retreive_Code()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    '~~> Set your workbooks here
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Unique License plate Valuation Algorithm.18March2014.V7.0.Winner!.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Complete Unique number sales.2010 - 2012.xlsx")

    '~~> Change these to the respective sheets
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Do the copy pasting
    With ws2
        ws1.Range("D12:D5283").Value = .Range("L12:L5283").Value

        DoEvents

        .Range("M12:M5283").Value = ws1.Range("L12:L5283").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range1.Value = Range2.Value` imo is better than copying then pasting for equivalent sized ranges. Otherwise, a clean answer :)

Comment: True @Cor_Blimey. Updating that :)